# Typing a date (element.send_keys) with Selenium/python/chromedriver, element.submit() crashes EMS web app

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

There is a calendar on a website and with Selenium/Python/Chromedriver I'm trying to select a certain date in order to modify the schedule for a given day.

```
time.sleep(5)
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']")
time.sleep(5)
#I clear the date that is set before
inputElement.send_keys("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b16/10/2018")
time.sleep(5)
inputElement.submit()
```

The code is fine, but on the webpage I get this:
[image]

EMS Web App is an application for a calendar, here the website:
https://www.emssoftware.com/resources/ems-web-app-datasheet#!

THIS IS NOT THE WEBSITE I'M TRYING TO USE BUT THE WEBSITE OF EMS WEB APP. I CANNOT GIVE THE RELEVANT WEBSITE BECASUE CREDENTIALS ARE NEEDED.
Is there any chance that I can handle it with Selenium? Why this piece of the website behaves differently? I'm a newbie of Selenium and all this stuff.

Comment: Which field on `https://www.emssoftware.com/resources/ems-web-app-datasheet#` page?

Comment: Sorry, that is the website of EMS web app! I cannot post the website I'm using because credentials are needed.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_

Comment: I cannot give the relevant HTML: you need credentials to access the page.

Comment: Are you running your brawser in headless mode, i.e., can you see the actions being performed on the screen? If so, is the values you're trying to set being filled correctly?

Comment: Yes, I can see the actions and the value is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different, and more usual, way to clear the field before sending the key value:

```
time.sleep(5)
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']")
time.sleep(5)
#I clear the date that is set before
inputElement.clear()
inputElement.send_keys("16/10/2018")
time.sleep(5)
inputElement.submit()
```

Comment: Sorry @Lafa, I had tried this method first. With this method the app crashes when the program sends clear(). I get internal server error.

Comment: Is there a submit button on the form? Have you tried clicking it instead of doing a submit action at the inputElement, as you're currently doing?

Comment: No. There is not. It appears like in this picture https://www.dropbox.com/s/g97qzux4zy8c9lv/Screen%20Shot%202018-10-06%20at%207.12.51%20PM.png?dl=0
If I do it manually, the "Enter" button does not work. I have to click outside of the window itself.